# Reduce the dataframe rows and lookup

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Need help with the following please.
Suppose we have a dataframe:

```
dictionary ={'Category':['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b','b'], 
'val1':[11,13,14,17,18,21,22,25,2,8,9,13,15,16,19],
'val2':[1,0,5,1,4,3,5,9,4,1,5,2,4,0,3]}

df=pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
```

'val1' is always increasing within the same value in 'category', i.e first and last rows of a category are min and max values of that category. There are too many rows per category, and I want to make a new dataframe that includes *min* and *max* values of each category and contains equally spaced e.g. 5 rows (incluing min and max) from each category.
I think numpy's **linspace** should be used to create an array of values for each category (e.g. `linspace(min, max, 5)`) then something similar to excel's 'lookup' function should be used to get the closest values of 'val1' from df.
Or maybe there are some other better ways...

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was playing around with linspace with making a for loop for each category. However, I am not able to progress with loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need ? with `groupby` and `reindex`

```
l=[]
for _, x in df.groupby('Category'):
    x.index=x['val1']
    y=x.reindex(np.linspace(x['val1'].min(), x['val1'].max(), 5),method='nearest')
    l.append(y)
pd.concat(l)
Out[330]: 
      Category  val1  val2
val1                      
11.00        a    11     1
14.50        a    14     5
18.00        a    18     4
21.50        a    22     5
25.00        a    25     9
2.00         b     2     4
6.25         b     8     1
10.50        b     9     5
14.75        b    15     4
19.00        b    19     3
```

Comment: Yes, this is excatly what I want and it works with the small example. However when I apply it to the original problem i am getting ValueError, saying - "Cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit" Do you know why it may happen?  One question about your code: what functionality does "_" in for loop?

Comment: That means val1 have duplicate , you can drop duplicate firstly using `df=df.drop_duplicates(['Category','val1'])`, also if this is what you need , would you mind consider upvote and accept it ?